# How Do I Change The Global Tint Color To Green Programmatically?

Tags: ios, appdelegate, tintcolor

I want to change the global tint color from the default blue to a dark green, preferably by adding code to the app delegate, but nothing I have tried works. I am very new to xcode, so if you could put your answers in simple terms, it would be much appreciated.

I have tried adding code from similar answers, but I am not sure where to put it, and yes, i think what i am trying to do is set the key window's tint color

```
@implementation NestopiaAppDelegate {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    GamesViewController *gamesViewController;
    GamesViewController *savedGamesViewController;
    GamesViewController *favoritesViewController;
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController;

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self setupViewControllers];

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)setupViewControllers {
    gamesViewController = [[GamesViewController alloc] init];
    savedGamesViewController = [[GamesViewController alloc] init];
    savedGamesViewController.saved = YES;

    favoritesViewController = [[GamesViewController alloc] init];
    favoritesViewController.favorite = YES;

    settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = @[ [self wrapViewController:gamesViewController],
                                         [self wrapViewController:savedGamesViewController],
                                          [self wrapViewController:favoritesViewController],
                                    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController] ];
}

- (UINavigationController *)wrapViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    // In order to avoid all the mess with contentInset on iOS 7, we just wrap each UIViewController in a navigationBar-less UINavigationController.

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    return navigationController;
}

@end
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Where in that code is your attempt to setup the global tint color?

Comment: i tried putting[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:(UIColor *)] in several different places (ie under "UIWindow *window"), but none of them worked, so i took it out. Sorry for the confusion. This is just the code before i attempted to change the tint.

Comment: All you need in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is `window.tintColor = [UIColor yourDesiredColor];`.

Comment: Thank you! do i need to put rgb values, or do i say something like blackColor or whiteColor?

Comment: That's up to you. Any `UIColor` object will work. How you create one is up to your needs. See the docs for `UIColor` for your options.

Comment: I put the code before the line [self setupViewControllers]; but it is not working. Did i put it in the wrong spot? Or is it in the wrong file? (the current place is the app delegate)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the UIAppearance proxy objects for that purpose. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

For example:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor greenColor]};
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You will have to change the color for each individual control though.

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants. I believe what they want is to set the key window's `tintColor`.